# Can I change a function reference of a class in ActionScript-3?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, reference

Ok, I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo extends Sprite {
    public function Foo(x:Number, y:Number):void {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public function bar():void {
        trace("I'm a happy class.");
    }
}
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
var foo:Foo = new Foo();
foo.bar = function():void {
              trace("I'm a happier class.");
          }
```

I'm getting this error from the compiler: "Error: Illegal assignment to function bar". How can I change the public function bar on the fly?

Comment: The Tyler Egeto's answer wroked. But now, how can I have access to the private members of Foo using the function assigned to bar?

Comment: This is now seeming like a strange request.  Why do you NEED to do this?

Comment: I just worked it out. I can use the keyword "this" inside the closure to have access to the members of the class Foo (just public members). And answering your question sberry2A, I just want to change the default behavior of an instance of the Foo class. I don't want to change the behavior of all instances changing the Foo class definition.

Comment: You could extend the class to achieve that functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that in ActionScript. There is a work around though, try something like this:

```
public dynamic class Foo{
 public function Foo() {
  this.bar = function():void { trace("bar"); }
 }
}

var f:Foo = new Foo();
f.bar();
f.bar = function():void { trace("baz"); }
f.bar();
```

**EDIT: OR THIS**

```
public class Foo{
    public var bar:Function;

    public function Foo() {
     this.bar = function():void { trace("bar"); }
    }
}

var f:Foo = new Foo();
f.bar();
f.bar = function():void { trace("baz"); }
f.bar();
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

I think the class needs to be declared as `dynamic`